# Inject bean property from outer bean

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, ioc-container

I have the following situation.

I have two beans, for example:

```
<bean id="service1" parent="txProxyTemplate">
   <property name="target">
      <bean autowire="byName" class="Class1"/>
   </property>
</bean>

<bean name="manager1" parent="txProxyServiceTemplate">
   <property name="target">
      <bean autowire="byName" class="ManagerClass1"/
   </property>
</bean>
```

And i have third bean which is really injected into those two baens:

```
<bean name="supportBean" parent="txProxyServiceTemplate">
   <property name="target">
      <bean autowire="byName" class="SupportBeanClass">
      </bean>
   </property>
</bean>
```

There is string "path" field in beans service1(path = "first path") and manager1 (path = "second path"). 
When supportBean is injected into service1 and manager1, I want that some string field in supportBean  (for example "actualPath") was automatically initiated from two enclosing beans. How could I do this in spring?

PS: I need that service1 and manager1 have supportBean with two distinct fields (in service1 class supportBean has actualPath = "first path", in manager1 class supportBean has actualPath = "second path)

I hope you understood me, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having seen any actual code, could you not set the `actualPath` on the `SupportBean` in the setter of the enclosing bean? The `SupportBean` would need to have a scope of prototype so that the separate state could be maintained.

So for example, if your `SupportBean` looked something like this:

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class SupportBean {

    private String actualPath;

    public void setActualPath(String actualPath) {
        this.actualPath = actualPath
    }
}
```

Then you could set the actual path on the `SupportBean` in the setter in the enclosing bean. So `Service1` might look something like this:

```
@Service
public class Service1 {

    private String path = "first path";
    private SupportBean supportBean;

    @Autowired
    public void setSupportBean(SupportBean supportBean) {
        this.supportBean = supportBean;
        this.supportBean.setActualPath(this.path);
    }
}
```

And `Manager1` like this:

```
@Service
public class Manager1 {

    private String path = "second path";
    private SupportBean supportBean;

    @Autowired
    public void setSupportBean(SupportBean supportBean) {
        this.supportBean = supportBean;
        this.supportBean.setActualPath(this.path);
    }
}
```

If you'd rather use constructor injection then just drop the setter and autowire the constructor:

```
@Service
public class Service1 {

    private String path = "first path";
    private SupportBean supportBean;

    @Autowired
    public Service1(SupportBean supportBean) {
        this.supportBean = supportBean;
        this.supportBean.setActualPath(this.path);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's quite nice variant, thanks :)
But how can I avoid the setting "path" through setter? Can I do this somehow through constructor?

Comment: @Dedyshka - You can use constructor injection to autowire the service. If you mean whether it's possible to set the actual path on the `SupportBean` via its constructor - that would be more difficult as Spring has already created the `SupportBean` by the time it autowires the services. You might be able to create a `SupportBeanFactory` or similar and autowire that instead. The factory could then create the `SupportBean` supplying the relevant path to the `SupportBean`'s constructor. It would really depend on what you're trying to achieve.